# When a SQL Server query returns no rows(NOT null rows) how do you include that in an aggregate function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a query to look for courses that do not have any of its gradable items graded.

In Blackboard when a user doesn't have a grade at all(e.g. no attempt was ever made) there simply isn't a row in the table `gradebook_grade`

So if a course doesn't have any grades at all the `gradebook_grade` table does not have any rows referencing the primary key of the Blackboard `course_id`

This is what I've used so far:

```
use bblearn
select cm.course_id
from course_main cm
join gradebook_main gbm on cm.pk1 = gbm.crsmain_pk1
join gradebook_grade gbg on gbm.pk1 = gbg.gradebook_main_pk1
where cm.pk1 = 3947
group by cm.course_id
having count(gbg.pk1) <= 0
```

The course in question(`pk1 3947`) is confirmed to not have any grades. So SQL Server says 0 rows affected, naturally.

The thing is, it doesn't select the course_id. I'm guessing `having` doesn't account for blank/non-existent rows. Is there a way to structure the query to get the course ID when there isn't anything returned? Am I joining on the wrong columns or using `where` on the wrong column? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join`

```
select cm.course_id
from course_main cm
left join gradebook_main gbm on cm.pk1 = gbm.crsmain_pk1
left join gradebook_grade gbg on gbm.pk1 = gbg.gradebook_main_pk1
where cm.pk1 = 3947
group by cm.course_id
```